# using domain expression in predicates

Tags: alloy

I am trying to write a modular predicate as follows,

```
pred total[rel:univ->univ] {
 all disj n, n': (~rel).univ | n in n'.rel or n' in n.rel
}
```

That doesn't quite work when I try to use a relation as in

```
sig Node {
 order: set Node
}

fact {
 total[order]
}
```

however I find that I have to specify the domain of n, n' explicitly as follows.

```
pred total[rel:univ->univ, domain: set univ] {
 all disj n, n': domain | n in n'.rel or n' in n.rel
}

fact {
  total[order, Node]
}
```

Is there a way to not specify the domain and have that be inferred automatically ?

Thanks
Vinod

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible.

You actually nearly had it in your first attempt. 
The tilda is actually too much. If you want to get the set of elements in the domain of the relation, you could write, amongst many different alternatives :

- rel.univ
- univ.~rel

  ```
   pred total[rel:univ->univ] {
      all n, n': rel.univ | n in n'.rel or n' in n.rel
   }
  ```

will thus do just fine

**edit**
If you want in your total predicate that the domain of the relation given as parameter consists of all the atoms of a given signature, without specifying the said signature itself in the total predicate in order to stay generic, one way of doing would be to make a new predicate of the sort :

```
pred totalDomain(domain:set univ){
     domain= Node ||
     domain= X ||
     ... // other possible domains

}
```

that would allow to enforce, without specifying a domain that the domain the relation given is "total" in the sense that it consist of all the atoms of an existing signature.

You would thus have :

```
     pred total[rel:univ->univ] {
        let domain=rel.univ{
           totalDomain[domain]
           all n, n': rel.univ | n in n'.rel or n' in n.rel
        }
     }
```

Comment: Why did you add the keyword disj to your quantification ?

Comment: Because that was a mistake in my original question. I fixed the original question. With the change, my question still remains. Even after your suggested change the 2 formulations give different model  instances. The one where the predicate totak has 2 parameter is giving the expected result.

Comment: All right, I got your problem, You want to make the assumption that the domain of the relation given in parameter consist of the full set of Node. This is indeed, nowhere defined in the total predicate I proposed. I edited my answer.